Two contradictory derivations of $\text{d}\omega$ for a $1$-form $\omega$ on a $2$-manifold.
I'm sure this is a silly question: there are two seemingly general equations for computing exterior derivatives that, when I apply them to a $1$-form on a $2$-manifold, yield different results. The first works for a $(m-1)$-form on an $m$-manifold: $\def\w{\omega} \def\dx{\text{d}x}$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\w & = \sum_{i=1}^m\w_i \dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge\dx^m\\
& \Downarrow\\
\text{d}\w
& = \sum_{i=1}^m\text{d}\w_i\wedge\dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge\dx^m\\
& = \sum_{i,j=1}^m\frac{\partial\w_i}{\partial x^j}\dx^j\wedge\dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge\dx^m\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i-1}\frac{\partial\w_i}{\partial x^i}\dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\dx^m.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The second one works for a $1$-form on any manifold:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d\left(\sum_j\omega_j \, dx^j\right) & = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i} \, dx^i \wedge dx^j\\
& = \sum_{i < j} \frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i} \, dx^i \wedge dx^j + \sum_{i > j} \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j} \, dx^i \wedge dx^j\\
& = \sum_{i < j} \left( \frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i} - \frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j} \right) dx^i \wedge dx^j.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
These first and second derivations, when applied to a $1$-form on a $2$-manifold, seem to imply, respectively, that
$$\text{d}\w = \left(\frac{\partial \w_1}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial \w_2}{\partial x^2}\right)\text{d}x^1\wedge \text{d}x^2
\ \ \ \ \text{ and }\ \ \ \
\text{d}\w = \left(\frac{\partial \w_2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial \w_1}{\partial x^2}\right)\text{d}x^1\wedge \text{d}x^2.$$
What am I doing wrong?

The $\omega_i$ are different in the two constructions. Write them out explicitly when $n=2$.
